# How to use Alamofire with Codable protocol and parse data

Tags: ios, swift5, xcode11, codable, decodable

Firs time using Codable protocol so many things not clear. After going through several tutorials started with the Codable thing to parse data. Below is the code:

```
struct MyTasks : Codable {
var strDateDay : String = ""
var strReminder : String = ""
var strRepetitions : String = ""
var name : String = ""
var strNotes : String = ""
var strUserId : String = ""

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case strDateDay = "duedate"
    case strReminder = "reminder"
    case strRepetitions = "recurring"
    case name = "name"
    case strNotes = "notes"
    case strUserId = "userId"

}
}

let networkManager = DataManager()
    networkManager.postLogin(urlString: kGetMyTasks, header: header, jsonString: parameters as [String : AnyObject]) { (getMyTasks) in

        print(getMyTasks?.name as Any) // -> for log
        Common_Methods.hideHUD(view: self.view)
    }
```

// Network manager:

```
func postLogin(urlString: String, header: HTTPHeaders, jsonString:[String: AnyObject], completion: @escaping (MyTasks?) -> Void) {

           let apiString = KbaseURl + (kGetMyTasks as String)
           print(apiString)

                Alamofire.request(apiString, method: .post, parameters: jsonString , encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers:header).responseJSON
                { response in

                let topVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //Common_Methods.showHUD(view: (topVC?.view)!)
                }

                guard let data = response.data else { return }
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let loginRequest = try decoder.decode(MyTasks.self, from: data)
                    completion(loginRequest)
                } catch let error {
                    print(error)
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
    }
```

Now, this is the response:

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "strDateDay", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"strDateDay\", intValue: nil) (\"strDateDay\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Below is the json response i am trying to parse:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "userId": 126,
        "name": "My task from postman ",
        "notes": null,
        "totalSteps": 0,
        "completedSteps": 0,
        "files": 0
    },
    {
        "userId": 126,
        "name": "My task from postman 1",
        "notes": null,
        "totalSteps": 0,
        "completedSteps": 0,
        "files": 0
    }
]   
}
```

I know i am missing something but even after spending more than half day i haven't properly understood what is wrong and where. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is with your struct the names of the properties in the struct should be match with json data or if you want to use custom name you should use `enum CodingKeys` to convert them to your liking

```
struct MyTasks: Codable {
    let data: [Datum]
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let userID: Int?
    let name: String
    let notes: String?
    let totalSteps, completedSteps, files: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "userId"
        case name, notes, totalSteps, completedSteps, files
    }
 }

    func postLogin(urlString: String, header: HTTPHeaders, jsonString:[String: AnyObject], completion: @escaping (MyTasks?) -> Void) {

       let apiString = KbaseURl + (kGetMyTasks as String)
       print(apiString)

        Alamofire.request(apiString, method: .post, parameters: jsonString , encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers:header).responseJSON
        { response in

            let topVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //Common_Methods.showHUD(view: (topVC?.view)!)
            }

            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let loginRequest = try decoder.decode(MyTasks.self, from: data)
                completion(loginRequest)
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
}
```

And one more thing keep in mind that you know the exact type of `notes` and make it optional otherwise it rise error, there was no type so I put a optional String in there.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Still getting error:  keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "userId", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"userId\", intValue: nil) (\"userId\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: That't because it's optional but in my code is not optional, change the values you know might be nil and you good to go, I'll update the userID

Comment: Thanks you gave the reason for the issue and provided the guidance towards the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your top JSON you have a single "data" property of type `array`.

You are asking JSONDecoder to decode a JSON object containing only "data" property into a Swift object called "MyTasks" with the stored properties you defined (including strDateDay).

So the decoder sends you this response because he can't find the strDateDay in that top object.

You have to make a top object for deserialization. Something like :

```swift
struct MyResponse: Codable {
   var data: [MyTasks]
}
```

Then just give it to your JSONDecoder like you have already done :

```swift
let loginRequest = try decoder.decode(MyResponse.self, from: data)
```

The data you send to the decoder is your full JSON stream (the data property of Alamofire's response object), and not only the "data" property of your JSON structure.

Comment: Why i am not able to access "getMyTasks?.data.name"

Comment: The JSON you shown is an ARRAY of the objects you've defined. And you explain you want to take it into a single object, that's not possible. Your "MyTasks" object is in reality a single "Task" object, contained in a "data" property of a "Response" object. You can only access to your tasks with accessing yourMainObject.data[0] and so on

Comment: Leave that, i got my mistake. Please do let me know how to add the "getMyTasks?.data in to array "var arrDayTasks = [[String: Any]]()"

Comment: "getMyTasks?.data" is already an array, access your objects like any array... i don't get what you mean sorry. Look at the end of this article, it's explained and it's exactly your case : https://learnappmaking.com/codable-json-swift-how-to/

Comment: Thanks your answer helped too.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest to use [CodyFire lib](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/CodyFire) cause it support Codable for everything related to requests.

Your POST request with it may look like

```swift
struct MyTasksPayload: JSONPayload {
    let param1: String
    let param2: String
}

struct MyTasksResponseModel: Codable {
    let strDateDay: String
    let strReminder: String
    let strRepetitions: String
    let name: String
}

let server = ServerURL(base: "https://server1.com", path: "v1")

APIRequest<[MyTasksResponseModel]>(server, "mytasks", payload: payloadModel)
    .method(.post)
    .onRequestStarted {
        // show HUD here
    }
    .onError {
        // hide hud and show error here
    }
    .onSuccess { tasks in
        // here's your decoded tasks
        // hide hud here
    }
```

Use `APIRequest<[MyTasksResponseModel]>` to decode array

Use APIRequest to decode one object